# Converting a nested list into a QTree Widget

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtreewidget

I have a list of files and directories, and I need to now build that into a tree structure, but I'm having issues adding them to the tree.

Example:
List of directories

```
directory=[["$Recycle.Bin","S-1-5-18"],["AutoDesk",["AutoCad","File1","File2","File3"],["Inventor","project1"],["WI","Copyright"],"Frank"]]
```

Setting up the Tree Widget:

```
    self.tab1.layout = QGridLayout(self)
    self.tree=QTreeWidget()
    self.tree.setAnimated(False)
    self.tree.setIndentation(20)
    self.tree.setSortingEnabled(True)
    self.tree.setWindowTitle("dirview")
    self.tree.headerItem().setText(0,"Directory")
    self.tree.headerItem().setText(1,"Size")
    self.tree.headerItem().setText(2,"Path")
    self.tree.headerItem().setText(3,"Modified")
    self.tree.headerItem().setText(4,"Accessed")
    self.tree.headerItem().setText(5,"Created")
    self.num_directories=0
    self.directory_parser(directory,self.num_directories)
```

Directory Parser function:

```
def directory_parser(self, directory,num_directories):
    for directories in directory:
        if isinstance(directories,list):
            Gui_Directory=directories.pop(0)
            self.tree.insertTopLevelItems(num_directories,"text")
            self.directory_parser(directories, num_directories)
            num_directories=num_directories+1
        else:
            File_name=directories
            print(File_name)
```

The out put should look like:

```
  $Recycle.Bin
       ->S-1-5-18
  AutoDesk
    ->AutoCad
          ->File1
          ->File2
          ->File3
     -> Inventor
          ->project1
      -> WI
          ->Copyright
  Frank
```

Comment: What should happen to `Frank`?

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot about Frank.  That's a root level file entry, so it should sit in the root directory.

Comment: That structure is incorrect for that kind of tasks, I would recommend using a dictionary dictionary and/or lists

Comment: A dictionary would simplify the data structure, but my primary issue is getting getting it into the tree widget.